# What does "lift" param means in the Spark FP-Growth algorithm?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, fpgrowth

I'm currently playing around with the basket analysis algorithm implemented in **Spark 2.4** that is called **FP-Growth**. When I display the association rules I see them with 4 columns: *antecedent*, *consequent*, *confidence* and *lift*. And my question is that I don't understand what *lift* column means. Can someone help me?

I add here some example data:

```
+-----------------+-----------------+-------------------+------------------+
|antecedent       |consequent       |confidence         |lift              |
+-----------------+-----------------+-------------------+------------------+
|[Water, Bread]   |[Chocolate]      |0.5555517002081888 |1.8312030635778151|
|[Bananas, Bread] |[Chips]          |0.4279642895327702 |1.8312030635778147|
|[Bread, Whisky]  |[Chips]          |0.30338071798697663|1.0               |
|[Bread, Apples]  |[Water]          |0.23370662601263412|1.0               |
|[Bread]          |[Water]          |0.17278234144521842|1.0               |
+-----------------+-----------------+-------------------+------------------+
```

Link to Spark FP-Growth documentation: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-frequent-pattern-mining.html

Thanks a lot

Comment: This article offers a very good explanation: https://towardsdatascience.com/association-rules-2-aa9a77241654.

Comment: Thank you @JamesChang, the link you provided helped a lot. I'm not sure if you should post here an answer with the lift information from the link or leave this as it